# Octobercms Possible to update multiple Models in one Controller?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

As the title suggests, is it possible to update multiple models in one controller? I am using Builder Plugin to deal with things. As I can see we can only choose one 'Base Model' when I create a controller. How do we do it?

Also a side question. I can see there are tabs that you can use in the form, but I never get to use them. I was up to the tabs when I consider updating multiple models, thought they might be used for such purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `Builder` is just for `kick-starting your plugin` or `simpler plugin development`,

if you need `some complex kind of stuff` then you need to **`develop/edit files your self`** as `builder` can **not** do that(**right now**).

> Its totally fine that you keep multiple controller for the multiple model, `personally i would say that will be the best practice`

**Different scenario:**

**But** however if you want to `edit other model's data from same controller` and also they have `relation to current model` which you are `currently editing` then I guess we can use `relation-manager` to show them as `relational-field` which show `list of related model's records` and upon clicking `list-item` you will get `modal` and `you can edit them there`.

**Another Different scenario:**

**May be if its not the case** then you need to `develop your own controller` you need to `render` your `forms` and `save` its data **manually**. (as we need **customized solution**).

> To start customization and build your solution this titorials will help you a lot.

**How MVC works in October CMS:** http://octobercms.com/support/article/ob-19
**Rendering Lists and Forms by hand:** http://octobercms.com/support/article/ob-20
**Implementing a nested relationship:** http://octobercms.com/support/article/ob-21

After watching this tutorials `you can develop your own controller which can have`multiple forms`and`lists`and you can`**save there data in single controller**`.

**Informational Note(side question's answer):**

they are `just tabs` normal tabs, Its there `because` if you have **`model with lot of fields`** you can **separate** them **category wise**.

**for ex:** 
**customer model**

- personal details can go on top level
- residency address and business address can go in address tab
- contact details can go in contact tab
- social details can go in social tab  etc..